# How can I set tag names when I serialize object to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, linq-to-xml

I tried to do it this way, but the tags in the final XML document are comparable to the names of the properties, but not my custom names.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
    // write xml into the writer
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(myClassObject.GetType());

    serializer.WriteObject(writer, sitemap);
}


[DataContract]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "customRootTag")]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "customTag")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "customItemTag")]
    public MyClassItem[] Items { get; set; }

    public MyClass(List<MyClassItem> items)
    {
        Items = items.ToArray();
    }
}

public class MyClassItem
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "urlTag")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "dateTag")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

How can I set own custom tag names instead of property names when I serialize class object to XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[XmlElement]` is for `XmlSerializer`. For `DataContractSerializer`, you want to look at `[DataContract]` (against the type) and `[DataMember]` (against the properties). You can set the name on `DataMemberAttribute`.

However! `DataContractSerializer` is *less flexible* in some ways than `XmlSerializer`. If you care about the xml layout, I would recommend `XmlSerializer`. `DataContractSerializer` is better for some other things (object tracking, for example). Pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `DataContractSerializer`, set the tag name on the DataMember attribute:

```
[DataMember(Name="YourName")]
```